# Summ up between events

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
  A.date as timestamp,
  A.driveNumber as 'Drive Number',
  SUM(2 * 6374.612 * asin(sqrt(POW(sin(radians((B.latitude - A.latitude) / 2)),2) + cos(radians(A.latitude)) * cos(radians(B.latitude)) * POW(sin(radians((B.longitude - A.longitude) / 2)),2)))) as KmDriven
FROM teslafiData A
JOIN teslafiData B ON (A.ta_id = B.ta_id + 1)
WHERE A.latitude <> '' and A.longitude <> '' and B.latitude <> '' and B.longitude <> ''
GROUP By A.driveNumber  
ORDER BY KmDriven DESC
```

This gives me `KmDriven` for each driving event. Each drive has its own `driveNumber`.

Now I need to get km drive between each charging event. Between charges there might be several driving events. Each charge is listed by `chargeNumber` and while charging the `driveNumber`is 0 and `chargeNumber` is counting up for each new charge.

Data Example in the DB:

```
ta_id    latitude      longitude  driveNumber   chargeNumber
1        47.xxx        8.xxx      1             0
2        47.xxx        8.xxx      1             0
3        47.xxx        8.xxx      1             0
3        47.xxx        8.xxx      1             0
...
80       47.xxx        8.xxx      2             0
81       47.xxx        8.xxx      2             0
82       47.xxx        8.xxx      2             0
...
151      47.xxx        8.xxx      2             0
152      47.xxx        8.xxx      0             1
153      47.xxx        8.xxx      0             1
154      47.xxx        8.xxx      0             1
...
256      47.xxx        8.xxx      0             1
257      47.xxx        8.xxx      3             0
258      47.xxx        8.xxx      3             0
259      47.xxx        8.xxx      3             0
```

**EDIT:**

I now managed to get the ta_id when a charging session ends and when it starts again. Therefore I need now to figure out how to calculate the distance between those two events

```
SELECT ta_id, chargeNumber
FROM (
SELECT ta_id, chargeNumber,  
       IF ( @prev_ver <> chargeNumber, 
           IF (@prev_ver := chargeNumber, 1, 1),
           IF (@prev_ver := chargeNumber, 0, 0)) AS IsDifferent
FROM teslafiData
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev_ver := '-1') AS var
WHERE battery_range <> 0 and latitude <> '' and longitude <> '' and latitude <> '' and longitude <> '' 
ORDER BY ta_id ) A
WHERE A.IsDifferent = 1
ORDER BY ta_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use '' to indicate missing lat/lng -- use `NULL` instead.  Meanwhile keep lat/lng in, say `FLOAT`.  See: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices

If you are using MySQL 8.0 or Mariadb 10, use `LEAD(1)` and `OVER ( PARTITION BY chargeNumber ORDER BY tag_id )` to get the calculate drive distances and the first lat-lng per charge.  In the absence of that windowing function, it would be better to do the arithmetic in your application.

1. Use `LEAD(1)` to find the distance for each distance.
2. `SUM()` with `GROUP BY` chargeNumber to get the total distance for each charge.

Be aware that the drive-distance falsely assumes a straight line.

Comment: thx, however I don't have the LEAD command..